# Expected value and variance of constrained samples from a binomial distribution.

Tags: probability

Assume we have a threshold $n_0$ on the samples from a $B(n,p)$ distribution. That is, in the sampling process, if we get a sample $x_i$ that is larger than $n_0$, we will discard it. Now, we get $m$ effective samples $x_1, x_2,...x_m$, all less than or equal to $n_0$. The problem is how to derive the expected value and variance of $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}x_i$. Intuitively, $E(\bar{x})<np$ and $Var{(\bar{x})}<np(1-p)/m$ since all samples that are larger than $n_0$ are discarded. But how to find the exact value of them?

Comment: Find a value for the pmf, and then [run the standard sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician). To get the pmf, take the original binomial pmf, zero out all elements greater than $n_0$, and then renormalize so that it still sums to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Given $p$, your probability of getting ${0, 1, 2, \ldots, n_0}$ remains the same, but your probability of getting a value greater than $n_0$ is $0$, so the probability mass function needs to be normalized to reflect the smaller universe. In other words:
$$
p_k =\begin{cases} \frac{{n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}}{\sum_{i=0}^{n_0}{n \choose i}p^i(1-p)^{n-k}}\quad 0\leq k \leq n_0\\
0\quad\textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Given the PMF, the expected value and variance should follow.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i follow your idea and find that it seems hard to find a closed form of the expected value and variance, how about we assume that the distribution is a normal distribution $N(np, npq)$?